# How can I slow down or disable cli wallet's automatic locking due to inactivity?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

While using `monero-wallet-cli`, I am frequently getting this message:

```
 ____________________________________________   
/ I locked your Monero wallet to protect you \
\ while you were away                        /
 --------------------------------------------
        \   (__)
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||


Locked due to inactivity. The wallet password is required to unlock the console.
```

How can I disable this behavior or increase the timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the wallet will ask for the password after `90` seconds of inactivity.  You can see this by loading the wallet, then running this command:

```
set
```

Look for the entry for `inactivity-lock-timeout`.

You can ***increase*** the timeout to say 10 minutes like so:

```
set inactivity-lock-timeout 600
```

Or disable this functionality like so:

```
set inactivity-lock-timeout 0
```

Comment: Maybe in combination with `set ask-password never` not sure if that one is necessary thou :) I had some problems with this, while running in `screen`.

Comment: @MogensTrasherDK Depends on your desired result.  I _want_ to be prompted when spending, but not for idle timeouts.

Comment: Tried to use `set inactivity-lock-timeout 0` in my .sh file to start monero cli, but no luck, it is still asking about password after very short time of idling.  `set inactivity-lock-timeout 0
./monero-wallet-cli --config-file monero.config`  What's wrong with my script file or with monero.config?